Cannot connect to apache superset database from host pgadmin or psql
Running the Apache superset Docker Compose, I am able to connect and query the superset database from within the docker, but running psql or using pgadmin from the Windows Host to connect to database inside preset docker gives me the following error:
psql: error: connection to server at "IP address", port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
I have modified the pg_hba.conf and set host to "*" in postgresql.conf. I have tried connecting with both IP address and name of superset_db container. Am I doing something wrong or is connection from outside of docker to postgresql database simply blocked for a specific reason? How do I connect my pgadmin to docker DB so I can directly import usernames into another database?

A configuration or network problem. There is no host parameter in postgresql.conf.
